# Session scoped JSF managed bean always null in servlet filter

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2, servlet-filters, managed-bean

I tried to create a Login filter like in this tutorial:

http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/jsf-2-login-filter-example/

The filter directs me to the login page, if I want to open a secured site. But when I push the login button, I see the login page again.

I followed the problem to login filter, where I try to get the loginBean from sessions scope. The loginBean is always `null`. According to the tutorial, my loginBean should be in the session because of the annotation `@SessionScope`.

My question is: How do I get my loginBean into the Session?

**Login.xhtml:**

```
<h:form id="login-form">
      ...
    <h:commandButton id="button" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>
      ...
 </h:form>
```

**LoginBean.java:**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true,name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4067847760780243370L;  
private static final String[] userlist = { "fuh:fuh", "huf:1234" };
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean loggedIn;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{navigationBean}")
private NavigationBean navigationBean;

public LoginBean(){}

public String doLogin() {
    String redirect = "";
    // Get every user from database 
    for (String user : userlist) {
        String dbUsername = user.split(":")[0];
        String dbPassword = user.split(":")[1];
        // Successful login
        if (dbUsername.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)) {               
            loggedIn = true;                
            Log.write("Benutzer " + username
                    + " hat sich erfolgreich angemeldet!");     
        }
    }               

    if (loggedIn)
        redirect = navigationBean.redirectToWelcome();
    else           
        redirect = navigationBean.redirectToLogin();            

    return redirect;
}
```

**LoginFilter.java:**

```
public class Loginfilter implements Filter {    
private LoginBean loginBean;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
     HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
     HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

     //this is always null
     loginBean = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("loginBean");

    if (loginBean == null || !loginBean.isLoggendIn()) {
        if (loginBean == null) {
            Log.write("loginBean null");
        }else if (!loginBean.isLoggedIn()) {
            Log.write("loginBean not logged in");
        }
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
        res.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login/login.xhtml");
    }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid the obvious: 1) Which package did you import `@SessionScoped` from? 2) Are you absolutely positive that it's the same HTTP session you're sitting in? (check cookies, session id, etc)

Comment: 1) javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped 2) You're right (tanks for the hint), the session ids are drifferent. How can I make the filter use the session, where the bean is in?

Comment: Just fix the problem of the session apparently not being maintained across requests. Check cookies in request/response headers, check if code doesn't unnecessarily do invalidate() on every request, etc.

Comment: Why do you have ` HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);`? Your users are either going to always hit the login page first (in which case, there will already be an active session) or they're coming from an unsecured page (in which case, the `loginBean` would not have been created and therefore always be null). There's no reason to have `req.getSession(true)`. Make that `false`

Comment: @kolossus changed that, but still isn't working. My code does not invalidate session,but I found something interesting in the cookies. When I print the value from cookie JSESSIONID from the loginfilter, it contains the sessionid.someNumbers, but when I print it from the loginbean it contains a number, which is not the same like the session id there but the same someNumber after the '.' What does this mean?